# SetBackgroundColor for Button from Resource file in Xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, button, xamarin.android, android-resources

I want to set the background color of a `Button`. I am using Visual Studio with Xamarin.

In Android we use:

**Java code :**

```
button_vstrong_fluorescence.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(InventoryActivity.this, R.color.linear_filter_background));
```

but In Xamarin
**C#** code.

```
button_vstrong_fluorescence.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#EBECEC"));
```

In **C#** the upper code is work fine.

But every time i want right this thing static way

```
Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#EBECEC")
```

Is there any way I can set `#EBECEC` this color from my Resource.

the `Color.ParseColor` require `String` value so .

### What I Try :

```
Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Resource.Colors.linear_filter_background.ToString);
```

But it give me below error.

[image]

Is there any way to set Background color from Resource??

Any help be Apreciated.

Comment: Hi,

Did you simply tried to put () after the ToString method.

Comment: yes i try but it give me error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an expert in Xamarin (or C#) but something like this should work to get your color resource:

```
button_vstrong_fluorescence
    .SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(
        ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.linear_filter_background))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try :

```
Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Resource.Colors.linear_filter_background.ToString());
```

Should work.